# A characterisation of a space in which a specific intersection is nonempty

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

In this [book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-0-387-75818-3) by Sahu, O'Regan, and Agarwal the following result is stated:

> Let $\left\{C_i\right\}_{i\in I}$ be an arbitrary decreasing net of nonempty closed convex bounded subsets of a uniformly convex Banach space $X$. Then $\cap_{i\in i}C_i$ is a nonempty closed convex subset of X.

---

We recall that: a Banach space $X$ is said to be **uniformly convex** if for any $\varepsilon,\;0<\varepsilon \leq 2$, the inequalities $\|x\| \leq 1,\|y\| \leq 1$ and $\|x-y\| \geq \varepsilon$ imply there exists a $\delta=\delta(\varepsilon)>0$ such that $\|(x+y) / 2\| \leq 1-\delta$.

---

My question: is there any specific class of Banach space in which the following condition is valid (I have the intuition that this is *similar to* some kind of compactness):

$$(\mathcal{J})\::\:\left\{\begin{array}{l}  \text{ For any arbitrary net of decreasing nonempty closed convex bounded } \\ \text{ subsets } \left\{\mathcal{S}_i\right\}_{i\in I} \text{ of } E,  \text{ the set } \cap_{i\in I} \mathcal{S}_{i} \text{ is a nonempty subset of } E .\end{array}\right.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a characterization of reflexive Banach spaces. To see it:

If $X$ is reflexive Banach space and $\{A_t\}$ is decreasing net of  closed bounded of convex sets then $\{A_t\}$ is decreasing net of compact sets in weak topology and hence $$\bigcap_{t} A_t \neq \emptyset.$$
On the other hand assume arbitrary net of decreasing nonempty closed convex bounded  subsets has nonempty intersection.

Take any functional continous $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ and let $$A_n =\{x\in X: ||x||\leq 1 \wedge f(x)\geq ||f||-\frac{1}{n} \}.$$
The sets are closed convex bounded and noneempty. Moreover $A_{n+1}\subset A_n $ and hence $$\bigcap_n A_n \neq \emptyset .$$ So take any $x_0\in \bigcap_n A_n \neq \emptyset$ then $f(x_0 )= ||f||$ and by Theorem of James we get that $X$ is reflexive.

Comment: Great, thank you! is it a classic result (that I may find in a book)?

Comment: I really don't know.

Comment: Yes, the unit ball is convex and the half space $\{ x\in X: f(x) \geq a \}$ is also convex. The set $A_n $ is an intersection of unit ball and half space so is convex.